# OLED_M01122 Letters Orientation

Tags: oled

I want to know, How Letters will display from following three types?

[image]

Comment: Which letters : ABCD or MF?

Comment: Just for example, I added ABCD.I want to know Orientation of  Numbers or any letters in the Display.

Comment: No datasheet link?

Answer (score 3):

From my brief read of the datasheet, it looks like this is a graphical (pixel only) display.  There is no character set built into it.

You can draw your own characters in any direction you like.